# Noindex,Nofollow in theme's header.php?

Tags: noindex, nofollow

My theme's header.php file contains this :

```
<?php if (is_search()) { ?><meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /><?php } ?>
```

What does that mean ? And does it affect my search rankings?

Answer (score 2):

I think not. Because it's not indexing the result page:

See:

```
<?php if (is_search()) { ?>
```

if is Search doesn't index or follow the page (for example to not show duplicated content). But you can remove the code if you feel you are losing views.

I was reading an [article about this](http://mikelittle.org/duplicate-content-in-wordpress/). Even if WordPress doesn't generate the /s=X page automatically, some plugins or even users can generate.

My recommendation is to keep the code.